# Sendind facebook messages with sleekxmpp without providing password

Tags: python, facebook, xmpp, facebook-chat

I have a simple sleekxmpp messaging bot that sends facebook messages (source: http://sleekxmpp.com/getting_started/sendlogout.html):

class SendMsgBot(sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP):

```
def __init__(self, jid, password, recipient, message):
    sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP.__init__(self, jid, password, sasl_mech='X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM')

    self.recipient = recipient
    self.msg = message

    self.add_event_handler("session_start", self.start)

def start(self, event):
    self.send_presence()
    self.get_roster()

    self.send_message(mto=self.recipient,
                      mbody=self.msg,
                      mtype='chat')

    self.disconnect(wait=True)
```

I use this test script to send try out message:

```
from split.apps.sapi.utils import SendMsgBot
jid = 'xxx@chat.facebook.com'
to = '-xxx@chat.facebook.com'
msg = "Try out message"

xmpp = SendMsgBot(jid, None, to, msg)
xmpp.credentials['access_token']  = [access token provided by Graph API]
xmpp.credentials['api_key']= [API key of our application]
xmpp.auto_reconnect = True

if xmpp.connect(('chat.facebook.com', 5222)):
    xmpp.process(block=True)
```

My problem is that it doesn't send messages when I don't provide my correct facebook password. Hardcoding the authentification mechanism to sasl_mech='X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM' didn't help. When I add correct password to SendMsgBot initialization, it sends messages without any problems:

```
xmpp = SendMsgBot(jid, password, to, msg)
```

Asking the user of the application to provide the facebook password is nonsense, I think the  access token and facebook id should be enough to make this work.